# Users search shows different reputation

Tags: discussion

Users search option in site shows a different reputation value near to user. But on clicking the use. his profie shows the correct reputation

Answer (score 8):

The user search option only shows how much reputation user has based on the time period you selected.

For example, if you are on the "MONTH" tab it will only show that users total reputation for the month.  If you want to see a users *total* reputation you need to select the "ALL" timeframe.

[image]